# aws snapshot for backup using cloudfromation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, snapshot

I am currently working on a CloudFormation project to build a fault tolerance architecture. I got a problem with the snapshot. I was trying to use EBS snapshot to store the data, so when one instance is down, other instance can load the data from the snapshot by autoscaling. Can anyone give some ideas, please?

Is the SnapshotId written by ourselves, why it is not visible in the console after creating the stack?

```
LaunchConfig:
Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
Properties:
  ImageId: ami-33f92051
  InstanceType: t2.micro
  AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'   #auto-assign public ip 
  KeyName: 
    Ref: KeyName
  SecurityGroups:
  - Ref: PublicEC2instancesSecurityGroupJing
  BlockDeviceMappings:
  - DeviceName: "/dev/xvda"
    Ebs:
      SnapshotId: snap-0821cc7c34fcb7b01
      VolumeSize: 8
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64:
      Fn::Join:
      - "\n"
      - - "#!/bin/bash -xe"
        - sudo yum update -y
        - sudo yum install httpd24 php56 php56-mysqlnd -y
        - sudo yum install mysql -y
        - sudo service httpd start
        - echo "<html><body><h1>Testing page !!!</h1>" >> /var/www/html/index.html
        - echo "</body></html>" >> /var/www/html/index.html
```

Comment: You cannot attached an EBS volume to two instances. Rather look at using EFS.

Comment: I also tried to use efs but failed to mount efs in LaunchConfig. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712540/how-to-get-the-cloudformation-resource-value-in-user-data-bash-code) Do you have any idea? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use EFS as an intermediate storage and mount it to each instance. Furthermore, you can use S3 bucket for such data. S3 is also may be mounted to instances as a file system.

- In order to mount EFS you need to install `amazon-efs-utils`
- In order to mount S3 bucket to your instances, you need you to install do
  next:

`sudo yum install automake fuse fuse-devel gcc-c++ git libcurl-devel libxml2-devel make openssl-devel`

`git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.git
cd s3fs-fuse
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl
make
sudo make install`

After you installed needed tools try to mount the bucket

```
s3fs your_bucketname /mys3bucket -o use_cache=/tmp -o allow_other -o uid=1001 -o mp_umask=002 -o multireq_max=5 -o use_path_request_style -o url=https://s3-{{aws_region}}.amazonaws.com
```

Add this process to your user data and it will be done each time after new instance is starting or create custom AMI